# Get renderings data source location

Tags: powershell-extensions

How to get rendering data source location either any one of below,

- Get items final layout renderings with their data source location
- Get rendering data source location by specific Rendering folder path.
  Ex: /sitecore/layout/Renderings/Rendering-folder-path

**Expected result:**

```
Rendering    |    DatasourceLocation
------------      ----------------------

{289347-238740-230489} | sitecore/content/datasource-location
```

I tried with ">Get-Rendering" this doesn't have datasource location property.Below list of properties available

```
PS master:\>Get-Item /sitecore/content/itempath | Get-Rendering -Datasource "*"

OwnerItemId         : 
OwnerItemPath       : 
Cachable            :
Conditions          :
Datasource          : 
ItemID              : 
MultiVariateTest    :
PersonalizationTest :
Parameters          :
Placeholder         : 
Rules               :
UniqueId            : 
VaryByData          :
VaryByDevice        :
VaryByLogin         :
VaryByParameters    :
VaryByQueryString   :
VaryByUser          :
ClearOnIndexUpdate  :
DynamicProperties
```

Even i tried below directly try to get rendering properties,

```
PS master:\>Get-Item /sitecore/layout/Renderings/Group/Navigation/Header

Name                             Children Language Version Id                                     TemplateName
----                             -------- -------- ------- --                                     ------------
RenderingName                           False    en       1       {} Controller rendering
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example, the item's `FinalLayout` contains the renderings.

```
$defaultLayout = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$rootItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{961563FC-3445-4558-BF3A-06DF06BA6298}"
Get-Rendering -Item $rootItem -Device $defaultLayout -FinalLayout
```

[image: Example]

From here you can filter out renderings that have a Datasource specified. In cases where the value is a GUID rather than a path you can use `Get-Item` to find out more details.